# React Typescript discriminated union gives compiling error but works on IDE

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics, discriminated-union

I have a component that has 2 properties. It may or may not accept one of those (say prop **b**), but you always need to pass the prop **a**. If the **b** prop is passed, it should change the typings of **a**.

```
interface FirstCase<T> {
  a: (param: CBParam<T>) => Element
  b: OtherInterface<T>
}

interface SecondCase {
  a: () => Element 
  b?: undefined
}

type ComponentProps<T> = FirstCase<T> | SecondCase
```

So, in my component im checking if the **b** prop is defined, and hoping that typescript infer the correct typings of **a**

```
function MyComponent<T>({a, b}: ComponentProps<T>): Element {
  return b ? a('some param') : a()
}
```

The thing is that in the IDE there is no error as I was expecting, but if I run `npx tsc` on the console, it complains that I need to pass a param to **a** (`error TS2554: Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Destructuring `a` and `b` does not help the compiler here. If you instead keep it as `props` and then test `b`, it "knows" that `a` is related.

This does work without casting or compiler errors.

```
interface CBParam<T> {}
interface OtherInterface<T> {}

interface FirstCase<T> {
  a: (param: CBParam<T>) => Element
  b: OtherInterface<T>
}

interface SecondCase {
  a: () => Element
  b?: undefined
}

type ComponentProps<T> = FirstCase<T> | SecondCase

function MyComponent<T>(props: ComponentProps<T>): Element {
    return props.b ? props.a('some param') : props.a()
}
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMICEAKcpwLYA8AKgHzIDeAvgFCiSyIoDyYAFtAJLjTxLFlVqtbgyTIAYsCgBnMKjjSI-CtWTI4ALmQAKAA458WjNlyFSASmQBeMgFEANhDwRwq5ACMtLdlC71eSqTUNML+jMgAyhAIAPYgACbyiipqmjqWNsgOTi5gbu4A-FoArgkQMKAQ8cFCYACeuiioMXi6cbmYUDG60spWElKySYFkAD6R0XGJChBCMKUIYMBxyACydc2t7eD8el09Ri1tIB37vRZa2c7gKWrIUBBgxVAgyLpnAHTuyAVvn3DaADk0haKH0pkBli07260g+APMwSAA)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need a type guard function: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html

Maybe specific example they use will help you:
`function isFish(pet: Fish | Bird): pet is Fish { return (pet as Fish).swim !== undefined; }`

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing type casting

`return b ? a('some param') : (a as SecondCase['a'])()`